# Window enter transition not working in android

Tags: android, android-animation

In an android app, i am trying to implement `windowEnterTransition`

From `activity A` i open `activity B`, in `activity B`, i have a `TextView` which i **want to slide from top to center of the screen** when `activity B` opens

**Problem**

When `activity B` is opened, `TextView` stays at its place.

**Question**

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

### Code

**Activity B**

```
public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);

        setWindowTransition();
    }

    private void setWindowTransition() {
        Slide textSlideDown = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);
        textSlideDown.addTarget(R.id.helloText);
        textSlideDown.setDuration(1000);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(textSlideDown);
    }
}
```

**Code to open Activity B from Activity A**

```
Intent openSecondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
ActivityOptions op = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this);
startActivity(openSecondActivity, op.toBundle());
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Slide a lot, but I think the `Gravity.Top` in your `Slide textSlideDown = new Slide(Gravity.TOP);` shows the direction of your slide and not the starting point. Try using `Gravity.Bottom` as this is meant to move the view from where it is to the bottom of its container.

([Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity#BOTTOM))

UPDATED ANSWER:
Make sure you have enabled window content transitions in your theme. Look at the steps as are defined in the [developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity#custom-trans):

in your manifest:

```
<!-- enable window content transitions -->
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
```

Comment: @Nick have you enabled window transitions? Declared the shared element?

Comment: tried it, didn't change a thing. There's not shared element between 2 activities that i have. I enabled `android:windowActivityTransitions` but unfortunately didn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

you should request the feature before setting the transition, i think in java it's like this
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS)